# jQuery 1.7.1 and Fancybox 1.3.4. not working - 'The requested content cannot be loaded.'

Tags: jquery, fancybox

When I'm trying to use jQuery 1.7.1 and Fancybox 1.3.4. i got the message - 'The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later.'

With jQuery 1.5.1 everything is OK. But other my plugins require 1.7.1 or higher version of jQuery. How can I handle it?

**EDIT** : code as in commnets

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.question_link").fancybox({
        'autoDimensions' : false,
        'width' : 500,
        'height' : 'auto'
    });
});
</script>
```

And I have a link that load with ajax partial with this modal window

```
<%= link_to "Reply", new_answer_path(question), :remote => true, :class => 'answer_link' %>
```

Comment: usually when you get this, you're doing something wrong

Comment: But no errors in console... Actually i don't know. Changing '5' with '7' in jQuery version and all crashed

Comment: could you share your code with us?

Comment: Solved by using 2 version of jQueries on one page with noConflict. There was no time and desire to digging what is really was wrong with fancybox.